# Why isn't Face Sets painting all the faces under the brush in Sculpt Mode?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, tools

In `Sculpt Mode`, when using `Face Sets Brush` on the mesh, the mask does not apply correctly to all faces below the brush. Some faces are ignored. This happens with any new object that I create.

I already tried to reset the presets of this brush, but it still fails. Is there an option that I accidentally checked that creates this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it. In `Brush` options of the `header bar` it is necessary to UNCHECK the `Face Sets` and `Face Sets Boundary` checkboxes. It is also recommended to have a not too high `Strenght` if you want to smooth the Face Sets (when holding Shift with the brush).

[image]

[image: Expected result.]